# Условие в DB laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function select($table, $kod_doc, $sum){

    $sales = DB::connection('mysql')->table($table)
        ->select()
        ->whereIn('KOD_DOC', $kod_doc)

    return $this->result($sales);
}
```

Есть рабочий метод, как вставить в него условие к примеру (ниже код не рабочий)

```
public function select($table, $kod_doc, $sum){

    $sales = DB::connection('mysql')->table($table)
        ->select()
        ->whereIn('KOD_DOC', $kod_doc)
        if($sum){->sum($sum)};

    return $this->result($sales);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так

```
public function select($table, $kod_doc, $sum = null)
{
    $sales = DB::connection('mysql')->table($table)
        ->select()
        ->whereIn('KOD_DOC', $kod_doc);

    if ($sum) {
        $sales->sum($sum);
    }

    return $this->result($sales);
}
```

Comment: Не работает, точнее не выдает данные а просто выдает информацию о запросе

Comment: @Федотов в каком плане не работает? Она модифицирует запрос если есть $sum